# To define CURRENT page for current menu item

Tags: php, menu, navigation

I've created a navigation menu by PHP.

1) I need help how can i change link class for current page. I mean for example when HOME PAGE is open link should be like class="bla bla CURRENT"

2) Is there any suggest to better way for the LINK to that buttons.
HERE IS THE CODES

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');  
$sql= "SELECT * FROM veri_kategori"; 
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
{
echo "<li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"".$row["link_tr"]."\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\">".$row["tr"]."</a></li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: 1) is easy – compare the address of the link you are outputting with the current address. (Look into `$_SERVER` if you don’t know the current address already at this point.) And your second question does not make any sense at all to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
<?
    require_once('../config.php');  

    // Get the current page.
    $pag = $_GET['pag'];

    if (isset($pag)) {
        if ($page == 'about') {
            // Redirect or include your page.
        } else if ($page == 'contact') {
            // Redirect or include your page.
        }
    } else {
        // Redirect or include your home page.
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM veri_kategori";

    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {           
        // Set default class.
        $class = "dropdown-toggle";

        // If home page, set another class.
        if (!isset($pag)) {
            $class = "bla bla CURRENT";
        }       

        echo "<li class=\"dropdown\"><a href=\"index.php?pag={$row["link_tr"]}\" class=\"{$class}\">{$row["tr"]}</a></li>";
    }
?>
```